# Can you remove Steamworks DRM from your own game after release?

Tags: steam

Is it possible to remove [Steamworks DRM](https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/api) from a Steam game after release? I'm sure that some developers have accidentally used DRM, without fully understanding the drawbacks for a consumer (the Steam client has to be running during gameplay, forced online checks etc.). **Using DRM is optional**, you can release your game on Steam without copy protection of any kind.
I haven't released a game on Steam, I'm asking for someone who has to answer.

Comment: There is drawbacks of having Steamworks DRM as far as I can see. There are no forced online checks unless you are trying to access online services, which require authentication anyways. Steam client running is merely a background process.

Comment: From the description on the API page, it sounds like the DRM is applied as a wrapper to the compiled game. So, would this not just be a matter of recompiling from source and electing to not apply the DRM wrapper? Or os the question about whether Steam itself will let you opt-out of the DRM wrapper for subsequent updates after initially publishing your game with DRM enabled? That latter question may be better to ask Valve's developer support directly, as NDAs might prevent devs from discussing the inner workings of the service publicly on sites like this one.

Comment: @Sam: I had to rollback your edit because the question is about removing DRM from an existing Steam game, not publishing a new one.

Comment: @user598527 Is this question about removing DRM from a hypothetical game developed by you? As in, if you choose to use DRM now, can you remove it later? If it's about removing DRM from existing Steam games not developed by you, then it's off topic here.

Comment: @user598527 Steamworks DRM is simply a wrapper around your exe. I was not talking about publishing a new one, but `republishing` the existing game without DRM as a updated version.

Comment: @MichaelHouse: yes, sorry for the late response